allow locally hosted dockerized django app to be accessed from the interweb through a local dockerized traefik instance?
The problem:
From a browser on my windows machine, I can access the default django page via:

localhost:5000
192.168.1.100:5000
But, not via my domain example.com

From the same windows machine:

I can access the traefik dashboard via monitor.example.com

So I know that the routing from the interweb to an internal docker container works.
Note: django app is minimum required for django app to display django default page

My home lab setup

using Cloudflare to point example.com to my external IP address
Local edge router port forwarding 80, 443 to docker-main server (x.x.x.165)
docker-main server hosting traefik docker instance
docker desktop on windows hosting simple django app (x.x.x.100)

Note: using cloudflare origin certificates, rather than letsencrypt
The traefik docker-compose.yml file is:
networks:
  mynet:
    external: true

services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/library/traefik:2.11.2
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      # -- (Optional) Enable Dashboard, don't do in production
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - CF_DNS_API_TOKEN=[cloudflare token]
      - TZ=[local timezone]
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro    # For the static configuration 
      - ./config/config.yml:/etc/traefik/config.yml:ro      # For any dynamic configuration you add
      - ./certs:/certs:ro                               # location for the certs
      - ./logs:/var/log/traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:[password]"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`monitor.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`monitor.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
    networks:
      - mynet

The traefik config.yml for the django app is:

note: removed other routing configs

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /certs/[origin cert].crt
      keyFile: /certs/[origin cert].key
http:
  routers:
    django:
      rule: "Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "web"
      service: django

  services:
    django:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.1.100:5000"

In the traefik.yml file:
global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

log:
 level: INFO

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    # http:                # commenting this out to just try getting http working first
    #   redirections:
    #     entryPoint:
    #       to: websecure
    #       scheme: https     
  websecure:
    address: :443

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: mynet
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/config.yml
    watch: true

The django docker-compose file is:

This is a cut down version from django-cookiecutter including the Dockerfile, removing unnecessary stuff for reference purposes

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_django_media: {}

networks: 
  mynet:
    external: true

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_django
    container_name: project_production_django
    volumes:
      - production_django_media:/app/project/media
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_postgres
    container_name: project_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    networks:
      - mynet

In django settings I have
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1", "192.168.1.100", ".example.com",]

Any other info required?
So what am I missing... :o(
Cheers in advance

I couldn't figure out how to use the config.yml to point to my django service i.e. what URL to use.
However, I did get it to work by adding labels to the django service in the docker compose file, sourced orignally from django-cookiecutter.
Reminder: am not using a certresolver/LetsEncrypt, rather using origin server certs from cloudflare.
Obviously replace example.com with your domain name.
volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  # production_traefik: {}
  production_django_media: {}

networks: 
  mynet:
    external: true

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_django
    volumes:
      - production_django_media:/app/project/media
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"           # This option overrides the provider value of exposedByDefault.
      - "traefik.http.routers.django.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.django.loadbalancer.server.port=5000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.django.tls=true"
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: project_production_postgres
    # container_name: project_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    networks:
      - mynet

